# How do I remove outliers from a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

The solutions I found online only show removing outliers from the entire dataframe, not just a specific column. So I'm having trouble figuring out how to perform outlier removal on a single column.

I tried creating a method, the code is shown below.

```
def find_outlier(df, column):
    # Find first and third quartile
    q1 = df[column].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df[column].quantile(0.75)
    
    # Find interquartile range
    IQR = q3 - q1
    
    # Find lower and upper bound
    lower_bound = q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    upper_bound = q3 + 1.5 * IQR
    
    # Remove outliers
    df[column] = df[column][df[column] > lower_bound]
    df[column] = df[column][df[column] < upper_bound]
    
    return df
```

But when I ran the code, it said "Columns must be same length as key".

The code I used to run is shown below.

```
df['no_of_trainings'] = find_outlier(df, 'no_of_trainings')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to remove values from only a single column, how will it fit into the DataFrame? or should it become its own Series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison result is by-index, so you can use it to reduce the DataFrame

```py
    df = df[df[column] > lower_bound]
    df = df[df[column] < upper_bound]
    return df
```

more concisely

```py
    ...
    return df[(df[column] > lower_bound) & (df[column] < upper_bound)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I got the same error message when running df['no_of_trainings'] = find_outlier(df, 'no_of_trainings')

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your `find_outlier` code except for the **return** statement:

Should be

```
return df[column]
```

You code will replace outliers with `NaN` values.

#### Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

def find_outlier(df, column):
    # Find first and third quartile
    q1 = df[column].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df[column].quantile(0.75)
    
    # Find interquartile range
    IQR = q3 - q1
    
    # Find lower and upper bound
    lower_bound = q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    upper_bound = q3 + 1.5 * IQR
    
    # Remove outliers
    df[column] = df[column][df[column] > lower_bound]
    df[column] = df[column][df[column] < upper_bound]
    
    return df[column]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'no_of_trainings':[1,2,3,4,5,1000,6,7,8,9,10],
                    'other_data':[1,2,3,4,5,9,6,7,8,9,10]})

df1['no_of_trainings'] = find_outlier(df1, 'no_of_trainings')
print(df1)
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]

#### Note:

The outlier of `1000` was removed.